Why is my French marigold dying?
I purchased a French marigold from Lowe and re-potted it with some of the original soil in my patio in a new pot. I kind in San Francisco and this is summer time so my backyard was getting 6+hours of direct sunlight. I had been watering it regularly and the soil was moist. It flowered twice in the first two weeks. But since then, it's been dying.
The flower is shriveled up, the plant seems to have stopped growing and is shrinking. The leaves had brown corners. I assumed it was too much sun and moved it into some shade but it hasn't improved in the last 2 weeks.
Recently, I moved it into an different kind of soil to see if that helps but nothing so far.
Can you help me diagnose the problem and what I can do to save this plant?
Is it some kind of disease?



Hard to say. I've had some trouble with red spider mites (which are quite tiny) on my marigolds this year - you might look VERY closely for very small bugs, which might not be those particular ones.

With respect of sun, I don't think you can expose them to too much sun at your latitude.  Its a long shot, but is it possible you were overwatering it?   I'm no expert here, but would it make sense to cut off the flowers so the plant can focus on growing its leaves/root systems?  (Maybe the microbiome change and transplant shock is just taking a toll on the plant?)
